# Some time Android Fused location client return wrong location (I am in India but it returns location for US Colorado)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fusedlocation

**Below is the code used for getting the location**

```
private fun requestLocation() {
        Utils.print("LocationUpdateService","request location per minute")
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }
        if (locationRequest != null)
            mFusedLocationClient?.requestLocationUpdates(
                locationRequest!!,
                locationCallback,
                Looper.myLooper()!!
            )
    }


  locationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
    locationRequest?.apply {
        fastestInterval = 1000 * (AppPreference.getLocationInterval(applicationContext)-AppPreference.getLocationInterval(applicationContext)/10)
        interval = 1000 * AppPreference.getLocationInterval(applicationContext)
        priority = LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY
    }
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(applicationContext)
```

Comment: Make sure you don't have any VPN application or fake location application on your phone.

Comment: No VPN application is installed on the phone, Only some times it will happens.

Comment: Are you testing it on Emulator, cause USA locations default for emulators ? Also there is cache of last locations.

Comment: No, Testing with real mobile device (OnePlus 9)